# How to use jQuery to generate 2 new associated objects in a nested form?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, nested-forms

I have a model called Pair, which has_many :questions, and each Question has_one :answer.

I've been following this [railscast on creating nested forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2), however I want to generate both a Question field and it's Answer field when clicking on an "Add Question" link.

After following the railscast this is what I have:

..javascripts/common.js.coffee:

```
window.remove_fields = (link)->
  $(link).closest(".question_remove").remove()

window.add_fields = (link, association, content)->
  new_id = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(link).before(content.replace(regexp, new_id))
```

application_helper.rb:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
   new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
   fields = f.simple_fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
     render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
   end
   link_to_function(name, "window.add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")", class: "btn btn-inverse")
end
```

views/pairs/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@pair) do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="well span4">
      <%= f.input :sys_heading, label: "System Heading", placeholder: "required", input_html: { class: "span4" } %>
      <%= f.input :heading, label: "User Heading", input_html: { class: "span4" } %>
      <%= f.input :instructions, as: :text, input_html: { class: "span4 input_text" } %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'question_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "<i class='icon-plus icon-white'></i> Add Another Question".html_safe, f, :questions %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Save Pair", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

_question_fields.html.erb partial:

```
<div class="question_remove">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="well span4">
      <%= f.input :text, label: "Question", input_html: { class: "span4" }, placeholder: "your question...?" %>

      <%= f.simple_fields_for :answer do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'answer_fields', f: builder %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

_answer_fields.html.erb partial:

```
<%= f.input :text, label: "Answer", input_html: { class: "span4" }, placeholder: "your answer" %>
<%= link_to_function "remove", "remove_fields(this)", class: "float-right" %>
```

I'm especially confused by the reflect_on_association part, for example how does calling `.new` there create an association? I usually need to use `.build`

Also for a has_one I use `.build_answer` rather than `answers.build` - so what does this mean for the jQuery part?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look but I still want to understand how to do it without a gem so I get a better understanding of Rails / JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

One way to check this out is to run through the helper script in the Rails console.

```
new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
```

You are taking the Form object and finding the class that it is for (f.object.class - in this case **pair**), then using reflect_on_association(association) - to return the AssociationReflection object for the named association (passed as a symbol from the arguments i.e :questions).

You can see all of these AssociationReflection objects for each class by using reflect_on_all_associations.

After this you need the class for which the AssociationReflection represents (which is why you use klass not class) - then you make a new instance of the class.

Why you don't use build_#{association_name} or #{association_name}.builds, instead of new is probably becuase the script doesn't know whether the assoication is has_one or HABTM, until it has already retrieved an instance of the associated object and the additional logic is not worth it.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html

By the way the revised railcast uses a slightly different way of generating the associated object: but the idea is the same (in this case you are sending - calling - a method on the form object then generating the related class)

```
new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
```

As for making using two models in the helper something along this line?

application_helper.rb

```
def link_to_add_nested_fields(name, f, association, nested_association)
   new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
   new_object.send(nested_association).new
   fields = f.simple_fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
     render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
   end
   link_to_function(name, "window.add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")", class: "btn btn-inverse")
end
```

E.g

```
<%= link_to_add_fields "<i class='icon-plus icon-white'></i> Add Another Question".html_safe, f, :questions, :answer %>
```

Comment: So would `new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new` basically be the same as writing `new_object = Question.new` in this case? The problem is that right now when I click the "Add Question" link only a new question field is generated (obviously), but I want to generate a new object both from the Question model and the Answer model. I've tried playing around in `application_helper.rb` - adding a line for Answer.new and calling render on it as well but it didn't work...

Comment: Pretty much the same - but as I think the Railscast goes through, by reflecting on the existing object associations you can use this generic helper method in a nested form of multiple levels.

Answer (score 0):

Below works. I am not using **form_for** in place of **simple_form_for** and **fields_for** in place of **simple_fields_for**. Thanks to Pasted

**def link_to_add_nested_fields(name, f, association, nested_association)**

new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new

id = new_object.object_id  # Need index, it's important. Inspect in browser

nested_new_object = new_object.class.reflect_on_association(nested_association).klass.new

fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => id) do |builder|

```
builder.fields_for(nested_association, nested_new_object, :child_index => id) do |builder1|
  render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", association.to_s.singularize.to_sym => builder) + render(nested_association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", nested_association.to_s.singularize.to_sym => builder1)
end
```

end

link_to(name, 'javascript:void(0)', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})

**end**